# requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(8, 'nodename nor servname provided, or not known'))

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to check a file containing urls which will return a response status code 200. I am using python 3.7.1
Below is the code that I have used

```py
import requests
import sys
url_list = sys.argv[1]
with open(url_list) as fp:
    for line in fp:
        response = requests.get(line)
        if (response.status_code == '200'):
            print ("%s is up "%line)
        print (response.status_code)
```

Above code is triggering error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 341, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 761, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 204, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 134, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 64, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 597, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 245, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 309, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 341, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 761, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 204, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 134, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 64, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(8, 'nodename nor servname provided, or not known'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "live.py", line 7, in <module>
    response = requests.get(line)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(8, 'nodename nor servname provided, or not known'))
```

Urls of the file used to txt

- https://www.google.com
- https://www.instagram.com
- https://www.facebook.com

The above urls when tested directly using `requests.get("https://www.instagram.com")` gives the desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove the trailing newline from the string:

```
import requests
import sys

url_list = sys.argv[1]
with open(url_list, 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        url = line.rstrip()
        response = requests.get(url)
        if (response.status_code == 200):
            print ("%s is up " % url)
        print (response.status_code)
```